# How to remove indent in first Paragraph

Tags: parindent, noindentafter

I am trying to make a CV and can't get rid of the first indentation in the first paragraph.

Both `\noindent` and `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` don't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for formatting itemized lists
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx} % allows for tables to be created by coloumn spacing instead of line spacing as in tabular
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%imports the a colour pallet for things like lines
\usepackage{colortbl} %allows colour fomratting for table lines

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % sets the column divider space in between columns
\date{} % Removes the date
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hfuzz=5pt % The \hfuzz setting specifies the maximum amount of box-overflow before a warning message will be issued.
\pagenumbering{gobble}%gets rid of page numbers
\title{\vspace{-1cm}\Huge Curriculum Vitae}
\author{\Large\textbf{NAME}\\EMAIL\\PHONE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\vspace{-10pt}{\color{RawSienna} \par\noindent\rule[3mm]{\linewidth}{0.4mm} } %[2mm] sets the vertical distance of the paragraph from the line 
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
{\color{RawSienna}\par\noindent\rule[1mm]{\linewidth}{0.4mm} }

\vspace{-10pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example is missing `\end{document}`  and it is not clear which indent you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

It is a word space not paragraph indent

```
\vspace{-10pt}{\color{RawSienna} \par\noindent\rule[3mm]{\linewidth}{0.4mm} } %[2mm] sets the vertical distance of the paragraph from the line 
                                                                           % %
```

remove the spurious spaces so the line is:

```
 \vspace{-10pt}{\color{RawSienna} \par\noindent\rule[3mm]{\linewidth}{0.4mm}}\par%[2mm] sets the vertical distance of the paragraph from the line
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! could you elaborate on this and the \par command?

Comment: @Matt You have two space tokens, you could just remove one and let it linebreak at the other but it is safer to remove both spaces but then the linebreak happens after the first blah, you want the paragraph to start with `Blah` not with the full width rule.